# how should i interpret the gjr-garch output where the gamma coefficient comes positives but insignificant?

Tags: volatility, garch

i run gjrgarch model on russia stock market where the gamma coefficient in gjrgarch(1,1) model output is insignificant but positive.
"gamma1 -0.026240   0.033785    -0.77669    0.437340"
how should i interpret  this?

Comment: It is unclear what the numbers in your citation marks mean? In general, an insignificant output implies that you fail to reject the null of $H_0: \: \: \gamma = 0$. Thus the magnitude of the estimated parameter is not significantly large enough to conclude that the true $\gamma$ parameter is not zero (or you are estimating $\gamma$ with large uncertainty/standard error arriving at the same conclusion). See these [slides](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_9628/slides/chapter3.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Variables Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
gamma1 0.046292 0.035958 1.28738 0.197961 we usually interpret gjr-garch output as "if the gamma coeffiecient is positive and significant that imply the presence of leverage effect" in above case the gamma coefficient is positive but its insignificant.

Comment: If your estimated gamma parameter, $\hat{\gamma}$, is insignificant, you cannot provide evidence for leverage effect in the Russian stock market (purely seen from the $\hat{\gamma}$ coefficient and its t-test), since you cannot conclude that the true value of the gamma coefficient isn't zero.

Comment: one of the scholars told me this interpretation that "the coefficient of gamma is positive which means the presence of leverage effect but insignificant. is this correct?